# Problems with Exim hosts_require_tls config

Tags: email, encryption, ssl, exim

I'm trying to enforce TLS for out going mail to a single host. I'm no exim expert, in fact I've never even used it, it was all set up by the previous developer.

I just assumed inserting hosts_require_tls = example.co.uk in exmin.conf and restarting the service would work. But when I add this line the service wont start. I checked in the "panic" error log after trying to start the service and it contains

"2011-08-02 12:20:18 Exim configuration error in line 150 of /etc/exim.conf:
  main option "hosts_require_tls" unknown"

So I'm obviously being dumb and putting it in the wrong config file or something. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting has to be put in the corresponding transport configuration section, probably

```
remote_smtp:
    driver = smtp
    hosts_require_tls = example.co.uk
```

by default. Not in the main configuration (where it is unknown).

Comment: remote_smtp or remote_smtp_smarthost are both located in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp` or `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp_smarthost` at least on debian and ubuntu